# How I can get the value of my UITextField?

Tags: objective-c

how I can get the value of my UITextField ? When I declare my UITextField in the Storyboard, I know but like this, I don't know.

(sorry for my English, I'm French)

Thank you in advance for your answer.

```
//Ajout d'un Text Field
CGRect rectTF = CGRectMake(10,70,100,20); // Définition d'un rectangle
UITextField *articleSaisi = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rectTF];
articleSaisi.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
articleSaisi.placeholder = @"Article";
[self.view addSubview: articleSaisi];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether you want to access the value or you want to associate your UI element to your code:

Try this if you are saying that you want to access the text value.

```
atricleSaisi.text
```

Try to control drag the UI element to either your corresponding .h or .m file so that it can create **IBOutlet** for you if you are saying that you want to connect your UI element to your code.

Highly recommend you go check the documentation.

Comment: Yes I want to create a IBOutlet. But I don't know how I can link it with my UITextField declared programmatically.

Comment: So, select your UI element from the Storyboard and control drag it to either .h or .m file you want.

Comment: I know how do that with the Storyboard, but here, I don't use it. It's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know when the user pressed return, as per your comment, then you should create a UITextViewDelegate for your text view and define its [textFieldShouldReturn](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:) method:

> Discussion
>
> The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the return button. You can use this method to implement any custom behavior when the button is tapped.

Also, give a look at textFieldDidEndEditing, which is called whenever there is a focus change and you should define to correctly handle user input.

Old answer:

If I do not understand you incorrectly, you want to create a `UITextField` programmatically (i.e., not through a Storyboard).

In this case, you should put you initialisation code inside the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller and make sure that you define a property for the text field instead of a local variable:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

....
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField* articleSaisi;
...
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {

   CGRect rectTF = CGRectMake(10,70,100,20); // Définition d'un rectangle
   self.articleSaisi = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rectTF];
   self.articleSaisi.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
   self.articleSaisi.placeholder = @"Article";
  [self.view addSubview:self.articleSaisi];
}
```

If you do so, you can access the text field value from any other method in the view controller through its `text` property:

```
self.articleSaisi.text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sergio. I know where put my code. In fact, my question is how I can get the value of my UITextField when the user presses on "Return".